# laravel 302 error while login with employee id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-5.4

**Problem:** I have user records each having unique emp id (integer 5), I am using my empid to log into the system but I am bumping into 302 error. now performing this while form data is posted with data :

[ **Note:** using Laravel Framework version 4.2.9 ]

eid = 938 , password = password

```
$userdata = ['eid' => Input::get('eid'),'password' => Input::get('password')];

if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    print_r($userdata);
    die();
} else {        
    // validation not successful, send back to form 
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

I get the data printed as array which means my authentication is successful but when i do a redirect it throws me a 302 error.

```
$userdata = ['eid' => Input::get('eid'),'password' => Input::get('password')];

if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    return Redirect::to('demome');
} else {        
    // validation not successful, send back to form 
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

**My Routes:**

```
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('demome',function(){
        echo "Asdasd";
        die();
    });
})
```

**Strange Behavior**

when the employee id is below 100 it works perfectly fine when its above 100, 302 error occurs

Comment: What's the exact error? Where do you use this code?

Comment: This is my controller code. when i look at the network log in inspect element I see that the route URL with error 302. i am adding my route code now

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no problem here. 302 is HTTP status for temporary redirection, so it's perfectly fine that when you get 302 status for your base url when using redirection. You should get 302 status for the url after posting data and 200 status for the url after redirection.

Comment: Marcin i have added the strange behavior to my question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

**Solved :**

had to use this in my user model

```
public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }
```